# Early to rise, early to go

Tags: riddle

> Early to rise
>
> Early to go
>
> Early to fly
>
> Early to know
>
> Early to see

**What am I?**

Comment: a model employee.... :p

Comment: many possibilities

Comment: closed at too broad, - got a worm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A Bird??

As:

> Starting three lines are self explanotory

Early to know

> A bird could detect wheather change in the early stage only

Early to see

> Could see a predator from a long distance

Answer (score 0):

is it ....

> TOO

it is always

> TOO Early to rise
>
> TOO Early to go
>
> TOO Early to fly
>
> TOO Early to know
>
> TOO Early to see
>
> and TOO early to sigh.

Comment: I don't think this is what questioner is looking for but it's funny and out of the box